# Can't resolve "onRequestPermissionsResult"

Tags: java, android, service, request, gps

I am a Game developer and not good at android. I want to make a library class that "extends Service" which sends the GPS location.

While I keep `onRequestPermissionsResult` in my exported google project in `"MainActivity"`, I don't get an issue. However, when I try to put it in my library class I start getting the following error.

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can't resolve `"onRequestPermissionsResult"`.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------

    package hp.test.com.mylibrary;


    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Activity;    
    import android.app.Service; 
    import android.content.Context;       
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;  
    import android.location.Location; 
    import android.location.LocationListener; 
    import android.location.LocationManager;  
    import android.os.Build;  
    import android.os.Bundle; 
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat; 
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat; 

    public class GpsLocation  extends Service {
        public static GpsLocation Instance;                       
        public  LocationManager   mLocationManager;                         
        public  LocationListener  locationListener;                        
        public  Context mainContext;                                             
        public  Activity mainActivity;                                                        
        public  String[] premition={Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};                 


        public static GpsLocation Instance ()                 
        {                                    
            if(Instance==null)                                         
            {                                           
                Instance = new GpsLocation();                                
            }                                                       
            return Instance;                                          
        }                                              

        public void setMainContext(Context context)                           
        {
            System.out.println("********** setMainContext");
            mainContext=context;
        }
        public void setmainActivity(Activity activity)
        {
            mainActivity=activity;
            System.out.println("********** setmainActivity"+ mainActivity);
        }
        public   void OpenLocationSeating()
        {
            mainActivity.startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
        }







        public void CreateData()
        {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mainContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationListener = new LocationListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    System.out.println("********** onLocationChanged"+location.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
                    System.out.println("********** onStatusChanged");

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                    System.out.println("********** onProviderEnabled");

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                    System.out.println("********** onProviderDisabled");

                }
            };
            checkPermissions();
        }





        public   void checkPermissions()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
            {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mainActivity,premition,1);
                }else
                {
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                }
            }
            else {
            }
        }




        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
        {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if(grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                }
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }  }
```

Comment: Here is the link for above code in a formatted way https://ufile.io/ghsaj

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override `onRequestPermissionsResult` in a non-activity class, in your case its `Service`. To put it in simple words, `onRequestPermissionsResult` is method in `Activity` class, hence can only be used in class which extends `Activity` class (you can also use `AppCompatActivity` for compatibility purpose).

The restriction also implies to [`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)). The first parameter itself is of type `Activity` and not `Context`.Passing `Activity` obj directly, to requestPermissions, in `Service` is not a great idea and bad practice since it would lead to memory leaks and debugging woes.

Move your permission request and response handling code in Activity and request permissions in activity.

Comment: I am passing main activity to  mainContext, mainActivity; This will not allow me to do the work ?

Comment: @user3336923 First of all it needs to be `Activity` object and not `Context`. Second, Its not  a great idea to do this, since it could lead to memory leaks and would lead to bad design